# In which cases is it okay to allocate on the stack

Tags: c++, c++11, vulkan

I am currently learning Vulkan. While studying several tutorials, roughly the same code appears repeatedly:

```
VkInstance g_instance;

void SetupVulkan(){
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo = {};
    //Set appInfo attributes

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo = {};
    instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
    //Set ICI attributes

    VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, NULL, &g_instance);
    //Error handling
}
```

This creates a `VkApplicationInfo` and a `VkInstanceCreateInfo` on the stack. Doesn't this lead to some problems, when leaving the function and using the `g_instance`? Is `vkCreateInstance` copying all the data of the `VkApplicationInfo` and the `VkInstanceCreateInfo`? If so, then why doesn't the official manual tell me about this behavior? https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkCreateInstance.html

The same pattern repeats throughout the API. How can I find out in which cases allocations on the stack are okay, and in which cases a more persistent way should be preferred like the Heap or Global Memory?

Comment: *Fair warning, I may be talking out of my ass*, though I've seen similar patterns before. I don't know anything about Vulkan, but i'd imagine `VkApplicationInfo` is exposing some setup stuff for the instance that probably shouldn't be messed with again. Essentially it's allowing you to set a few things (I've no idea what) and then likely copying a few things into your `VkInstance `. I'd imagine the amount copied is small and the minimal "run time" cost is well worth it over having essentially dead information persist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to remember which objects represent you giving data to Vulkan and which represent Vulkan objects or Vulkan giving data back to you.

`VkInstance` is a Vulkan handle. That means that it is effectively a pointer or 64-bit integer or somesuch. You use it like a pointer to an object, not like the object itself. So it's functionally no different from this:

```
Type *p
auto error_code = getPtr(&p);
return p;
```

All objects that Vulkan creates (ie: the results of `vkCreate` or `vkAllocate` calls) are handles. They all act like pointers/references, so you can pass them around freely without concern.

Actual Vulkan structures, like the various `Info` objects, are used either for input to Vulkan or output from Vulkan. But either way, Vulkan will only use them for the duration of the function call. So what you do with them afterwards is entirely up to you.

Even output data structures like `VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures` are still just C++ structs. And you use them in whatever way C++ permits. The data in them doesn't have additional references or pointers to Vulkan-owned memory; they're just a bundle of values.

If you use `VkAllocationCallbacks`, you do have to take some care. The implementation will store the pointers stored in this struct internally. So they need to remain valid until you destroy the associated object. But the struct itself will not be stored beyond the duration of the Vulkan call that you give it.

> If so, then why doesn't the official manual tell me about this behavior?

It does, in section 2.3.1. This applies to *every function* in the Vulkan specification, so it's not listed on each one individually:

> Application-owned memory is immediately consumed by any Vulkan command it is passed into. The application can alter or free this memory as soon as the commands that consume it have returned.

Comment: There is a half-decent "why C APIs use pointers" Q&A around here somewhere.  But a description why the API takes these structs by pointer instead of value might be illuminating here?  In a completely unrelated note, while searching for it, I found [SOaaS](https://medium.com/pointer-io/stack-overflow-as-a-service-eb86bd4b6fdd), which is utterly unrelated and delightful.

Comment: _why the API takes these structs by pointer instead of value_, because the structs are large, so copying them by value is an unnecessary cost.